# Suppose $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix that contains a column vector of ones, how does it look $(X^TX)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppode $X$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, with rank $p$ and $p<n$, such that it can be partitioned into $X=[1\,\lvert\,X_2]$ then if we write: $$(X^TX)^{-1}=B=\begin{pmatrix}
B_{11}&B_{12}\\
B_{21}&B_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $B_{22}=[X_2^T(I_n-\frac1{n}11^T)X_2]$, where $11^T$ is a matrix of ones.

I have this .pdf that describes the inverse of a partitioned matrix and how does it look like: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf

But I don't know to propose the partition or if there's a better way. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$X^\top X = \begin{bmatrix}n & 1^\top X_2\\X_2^\top 1 & X_2^\top X_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

The block $B_{22}$ that you desire can is the Schur complement of the bottom-right block of $X^\top X$. (See $M/D$ at the top of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).)

Thus,
with $A=n$, $B=1^\top X_2$, $C=X_2^\top 1$, and $D=X_2^\top X_2$, we have
$$B_{22} = X_2^\top X_2 - (X_2^\top 1) \frac{1}{n} (1^\top X) = X_2^\top \left(I_n - \frac{1}{n} 11^\top\right)X_2.$$

---

Remark: the entire matrix $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ (not just $B_{22}$) can be computed using the Schur complement of either the upper-left or the bottom-right block. The [derivation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background) opts to use the upper-left corner instead of the bottom-right corner. For the derivation with the bottom-right corner, see the bottom of page two of [this pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf). In particular, you see that the bottom right corner of the inverse is the Schur complement of the bottom-right block of the original matrix, as I stated above.